# Limit multiple selection in react

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I was trying to figure out how to limit the number of selections in the multiselect option. For example: if my total number of options are 6, but the user should not select more than 3.
Here is my code, and I am making a react based project

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';



function CoFounder() {
    return (
    <>
      <div class="mkw_figure">
       <h1 class="mkw_headline">
        Co Founders Match 
        </h1> 

        <h5 class="mkw_subheadline">
          Get the best matching Co Founder profile to connect and try your startup
        </h5>

        <h3 class="mkw_subheadline" style={{fontSize: 'x-large', margin: '0px', float: 'left', marginLeft: '80px', display: 'inline'}}>
          Co Founder skills you require
        </h3>

        <TextField placeholder="First skill would be priority skill. Type Own or Select from below"></TextField> 

<div id="pill_multiselect" class="pill_multiselect">

    <label class="PillList-item">
  <input type="checkbox" name="feature" onClick="return myfun()" value="1" />
  <span class="PillList-label">Business Development
  <span class="Icon Icon--checkLight Icon--smallest"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>

  </span>
</label>
    <label class="PillList-item">
  <input type="checkbox" name="feature" onClick="return myfun()" value="2" />
  <span class="PillList-label">Marketing
  <span class="Icon Icon--checkLight Icon--smallest"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>

  </span>
</label> <label class="PillList-item">
  <input type="checkbox" name="feature" onClick="return myfun()" value="3" />
  <span class="PillList-label">Coding
  <span class="Icon Icon--checkLight Icon--smallest"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>

  </span>
</label>
<label class="PillList-item">
  <input type="checkbox" name="feature" onClick="return myfun()" value="3" />
  <span class="PillList-label">UI/UX
  <span class="Icon Icon--checkLight Icon--smallest"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
  </span>
</label><label class="PillList-item">
  <input type="checkbox" name="feature" onClick="return myfun()" value="3" />
  <span class="PillList-label">Product Management
  <span class="Icon Icon--checkLight Icon--smallest"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>

  </span>
</label><label class="PillList-item">
  <input type="checkbox" name="feature" onClick="return myfun()" value="3" />
  <span class="PillList-label">Leadership
  <span class="Icon Icon--checkLight Icon--smallest"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>

  </span>
</label><label class="PillList-item">
  <input type="checkbox" name="feature" onClick="return myfun()" value="3" />
  <span class="PillList-label">Operations
  <span class="Icon Icon--checkLight Icon--smallest"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>

  </span>
</label>
  </div>
<div> <span id="not-valid" style={{color:'red'}}> </span></div>

 <button class="mkw_test_apply_btn">Search</button>
      </div>    
    </>
  );
}


export default CoFounder;
```

From the previous discussions on this topic, I got to know that I can use this to limit selection

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function() {

          var last_valid_selection = null;

          $('#userRequest_activity').change(function(event) {

            if ($(this).val().length > 3) {

              $(this).val(last_valid_selection);
            } else {
              last_valid_selection = $(this).val();
            }
          });
        });
        </script>
```

But then I am not able to copy this in my react file, it is giving me error. Please suggest a way how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Inside you `onClick` function increment a counter (state variable) and if it's 3 just disable the checkboxes, like so:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

const myFun = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
}

return (
    ...
    <input disabled={counter >= 3} ... />
    ...
);
```

**edit**
Try:

```
<input {counter >= 3 ? disabled : } ... />
```

Comment: Have you tried encorporating it in code, because this method is not working for me. I am still able to select more then 3options.

Comment: @JanenderSharma I've added an edit